# Example of a codimension one variety with no local equation?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The existence of a local equation for a codimension one variety around a smooth point in the ambient space has many nice consequences. I am wondering if someone knows of an example of a variety $Y$ of codimension one in a variety $X$ with a singularity at P, such that $Y$ has no local equation in $X$ at $P$.

Comment: What's a local equation? Do you mean an uniformizer for the local ring? I this case, pick a plane curve that have two tangent lines at a given point, then the local ring is not a discrete valuation ring and the maximal ideal is generated by any linearly independent two lines that are not tangent.

Comment: @user40276 I mean a generator of the ideal of subvariety in the local ring. I think it is the same concept. I think in my mind I wanted something of higher dimension, but I can't believe I didn't think to look at examples. Thanks!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I wanted an ambient point that was not smooth, because I wanted to see an example of a subvariety of codimension 1 that had no local equation.

Comment: I had given this earlier. Just take the 'universal example' with $X$ defined by $xy-zw=0$ in 4-space and take $Y$ to be the codimension one subset defined by say $x=z=0$. This has no `local equation' near the origin.

Comment: Dear AreaMan,  you are right: I misread your very clear question. Apologies.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg No problem at all. :)